# How can I create view as below

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create view as below. In this, I used various layouts viewgroup. But the problem in that group is, first or last button is leaving some space start and end respectively. I want to create no space in start of the Button and No space at the end of the button and View should look like this.

I would be grateful for your help.

[image]

Comment: Try adding these properties ```android:insetLeft="0dp" android:insetRight="0dp"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) for providing packed chain constraint, which uses same weighted UI as LinearLayout. I used `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"` and
`app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"` attribute to achieve. See the image and source code below.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_qr_scan_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_two"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button_three"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_three"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_one"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_two"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Constraint Layout, you can do like this :

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Material Design Theme achieving this is easy :

https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/desired_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Style Folder :

```
<style name="desired_button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon">
    <item name="iconGravity">textStart</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">Your Desired color</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/pro_button_shape_appereance</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="iconPadding">4dp</item>
    <item name="icon">Desired drawable</item>
</style>

<style name="pro_button_shape_appereance" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">20dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]